# Contextual Image Delivery service throwing error

Tags: web8, contextual-image-delivery

I have installed contextual image delivery microservice. It was successfully installed as a window service and running. I have followed [SDL documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-4BE1C525-4D92-4B04-A434-6A96C16606ED#docid=GUID-4BE1C525-4D92-4B04-A434-6A96C16606ED&filename=GUID-4BE1C525-4D92-4B04-A434-6A96C16606ED.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4BE1C525-4D92-4B04-A434-6A96C16606ED) to setup the service but when I browse it shows the below error[image]

My discovery and CID service are setup on a single machine so I have also added below argument in the installService.ps1 script -
$arguments += "++DependsOn=SDLWebDiscoveryService"
as per documentation.

If anybody have the context of this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you see anything in logs or event handler?

Answer (score 1):

I think the base path you are using is incorrect, it should i think be 'http://host:8088/cid'